# Merge an entire Geodatabase in ESRI ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, file-geodatabase, merge

How can I merge an entire Geodatabase in the ESRI (ArcView) ModelBuilder? I have several FeatureClasses created into the GDB and in the model I plan to merge them all. Right now I have imported all the FCs by hand into the Model. This is not the solution I am aiming for because the names and the amount of FCs could vary.

Comment: Use Append (Data Management) http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000050000000 and the NO_TEST option

Comment: This doesn't work out. I still have to select all including FCs manually.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this using this python script, here is the syntax:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:\\temp\\test.gdb"
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('','')
arcpy.Merge_management(fcList, "Merge")
```

Just change the env workspace to match your geodatabase path.

Comment: Using the List function will do the trick.  Is there a way to use the Batch functionallity of a tool in ModelBuilder?

Comment: @dohaboya, Yes, the merge tool can be run in batch mode.  Right click the input feature cell and select 'Insert values from a table'.

Answer (score 0):

You can Batch this process by  [creating an Input Table](http://www.aubreyrhea.net/gis/index.php/tag/model-builder/).  This will allow you to load as many FCs as you like.  It would probably be beneficial if they are all located in the same directory.

Comment: As far as I know this makes the Merge tool run n times, when I have n files. I want to run merge only one time, to merge all n files.